# how to express $t$ using $v_0$, $\alpha$, $g$, $\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

$$v_0\cos\alpha=gt\sin\theta$$
$$v_ot\sin\alpha =\frac12gt^2\cos\theta$$

I want to write $t$ using $v_0$, $\alpha$, $g$, $\theta$.

But I don't have any idea. Help me

Comment: Get an expression for cos(alpha) and sin(alpha) and use the standard trig identity $cos(x)^2+sin(x)^2=1$

Comment: In the first equation, you already have t in function of $\alpha ;\theta; v_0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: After correction you will get
$$v_0\cos(\alpha)=gt\sin(\theta)$$
$$2v_0\sin(\alpha)=gt\cos(\theta)$$
After multiplication you woll get
$$2v_0^2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)=(gt)^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$
Can you finish?

Comment: sorry, LHS is $v_o t\sin\alpha$, not $v_o \sin\alpha$.